# Some Sum of Squares Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, summation, means, sums-of-squares

I want to prove the following: Let $\{\sigma_{(m,k)}\}_{m,k}$ be a family of positive real values with $m=1,\ldots,NL$ and $k=1,\ldots,K$ where $N,L,K\in\mathbb{N}$. This family satisfies that $\sigma_{(m+1,k)}\leq \sigma_{(m,k)}$ for all $k$ and $m$. Then,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{m=L+1}^{NL}\sigma_{(m,k)}^2\leq\frac{1}{LK}\left(\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{m=1}^{NL}\sigma_{(m,k)}\right)^2
\end{equation}

It is possible to prove the case $K=1$ because you can define the family of index $\{I_n\}$ such that $I_n = \{m\in\mathbb{N}:1+(n-1)L\leq m\leq1+nL\}$. Then you have that for all $n=1,..,N/L-1$,
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{(\hat{m})}\leq\frac{1}{L}\sum_{m\in I_n}\sigma_{(m)}\qquad \forall\hat{m}\in I_{n+1}  \qquad(\dagger)
\end{equation}

Then, using $(\dagger)$ you have

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{m=L+1}^{NL}\sigma_{(m)}^2&=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{n=2}^{N/L}\sum_{m\in I_n}\sigma_{(m)}^2\leq\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{n=2}^{N/L}\sum_{m\in I_n}\left(\frac{1}{L}\sum_{m\in I_{n-1}}\sigma_{(m)}\right)^2\\
&\leq\leq\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{n=2}^{N/L}\frac{1}{L}\left(\sum_{m\in I_{n-1}}\sigma_{(m)}\right)^2\leq\frac{1}{L}\left(\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{m=1}^{NL}\sigma_{(m)}\right)^2
\end{align}

But I have not been able to prove the general case.

Comment: Are you sure about case $K=1$? That's not simple

Comment: Please, check the edition

Comment: Ok  $N/L$ is $N$ and $\le \le $ is equality i guess. Tx

Comment: The case $K=1$ is proved   for any $k$, a hint towords a counterexample maybe $K=2$, $$a_k=\sum_{m=L+1}^{NL}\sigma_{(m,k)}^2\le\frac{1}{L}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{(N-1)L}\sigma_{(m,k)}\right)^2=b_k^2$$ If $\forall k$, $a_k\le b_k^2$ then we got $$\sum_{k=1}^K a_k\le \dfrac{1}{K}(\sum_{k=1}^K b_k)^2$$
but if $K=2$ and $a_k=b_k^2$, inequality is reversed.

Comment: I don't see why $a_k\leq b_k^2$ implies 
$$\sum_{k=1}^K a_k\le \dfrac{1}{K}(\sum_{k=1}^K b_k)^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Suppose $\sigma_{(m,1)}=1$ for every $m$ and $\sigma_{(m,k)}=\epsilon>0$ for every $k>1$. Then
\begin{aligned}
A&=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{m=L+1}^{NL}\sigma_{(m,k)}^2
=(N-1)L\left[1+(K-1)\epsilon^2\right],\\
B&=\frac{1}{LK}\left(\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{m=1}^{NL}\sigma_{(m,k)}\right)^2
=\frac{N^2L}{K}\left[1+(K-1)\epsilon\right]^2.
\end{aligned}
Therefore $A>B$ when $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small and $(N-1)K>N^2$.